# virt-manager cannot identify machine

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager, virsh

last time I had virt-manager + Desktop on my centos server everything was fine then I removed desktop for more security. and after a while I installed it again and now when I open virt-manager it doesn't show the list of KVMs but it's connected and displays the details.

can anyone please explain how Can I fix it ?

Comment: Explain what do you mean by saying *it doesn't show the list of KVMs but it's connected and displays the details*? What details does it show then? Also you don't really need GUI on your server, it's a server afterall. Simple `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all` would do.

Comment: Thanks, I mean by clicking on `localhost (QEMU)` It's pops a windows containing details. I could connect to virt-manager remotely and it works fine. I need GUI to create VMs. Thanks

Comment: It contains details of what? Of the connection? Or does it show the list of kvm guests? Also, you can't connect *to* virt-manager since it is a GUI, but you can connect *with* it *to* a remote server, that's what I usually do to manage my hosts usually.

Comment: When I open virt-manager in my server from VNC, It shows the hypervisor connection but I also have 5 VMs running that it doesn't show those VMs. details is equal to right clicking on hypervisor connection and select details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you KVM host server's (CentOS) IP is `$SERVER`.

Run the following in console:

```
localhost$ virsh -c qemu+ssh://$SERVER/system list --all
```

This should show the list of libvirt quests as seen from your PC.  Here's an example output (taken from my server):

```
 ID Name                 Status
----------------------------------
  1 freebsd9             running
  3 router               running
  - node1                shut off
```

Now run this:

```
localhost$ ssh $SERVER
centos-server$ virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
```

This should show the list of libvirt quests as seen from the server. Here's an example output (taken from my server):

```
 ID Name                 Status
----------------------------------
  1 freebsd9             running
  3 router               running
  - node1                shut off
```

As you can see the outputs are pretty much the same, as they should be.

In your case both of them should list 5 running guests. If not, you can at least figure out "who's lying", the local *vision* or the remote one.

**EDIT:**

You don't need to connect to your CentOS server via VNC just to have virt-manager's GUI to config your KVM guests. As I already said having a GUI on the server installed is... weird, bad practice, etc.

Instead install virt-manager *on your local PC* and connect from it to the CentOS server. It even works faster since you don't work over vnc!

Just add a new remote connection via `File > Add Connection` menu of the virt-manager, then fill your connection details like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, listing VMs is not the only problem I want to edit them through virt-manager and something I noticed now is it works fine remotely but on It doesn't work through VNC in my server

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this before but it's way too slow. I don't know why. SSH and VNC are OK but remote virt-manager is very slow. what do you think causes this?

Comment: What exactly is *very slow*? GUI response? Locally running GUI applications will **always** perform better then the ones shown via some kind of remote desktop (VNC, RDP, whatever). From my experience managent of remote KVM-hosts in virt-manager performs are smooth as the local ones.

Comment: I can easily manage VMs via VNC but Yes GUI response in remote virt-manager is really a pain.

Comment: That's exactly what I am suggesting to fix: run virt-manager *locally* and connect to the *remote* libvirt host instead of running virt-manager *remotely via VNC* but connecting to a *local* libvirt host.

Comment: Sorry but what you suggest to do is what I mean. that's slow. and VNC is faster for me. I'm a bit confused :D